# Streaming PC with windows 8 to a TV over network

Tags: windows-8, video, streaming, tv

I have a LG TV. I have noticed that I can stream most movie files, for example mp4. files using windows media player, by right clicking on the video->Play to -> LG TV.

I am interested if I can stream my whole screen. (I cannot find my Tv on screen resolution options), or if I can stream videos from the internet atleast, say youtube and so on.. I have searched for this for some time, no luck, so I thought I'd ask it here.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a WiDi capable TV and a WiDi capable WiFi adapter, streaming a desktop to a TV is never going to be possible. This is because Display over WiFi, or WiDi uses a special protocol (and special hardware) to stream or broadcast your PCs desktop, much like a RTMP stream requires software to be able to grab that stream

Comment: When you talk about his WiDi capable Wifi adapter, im guessing your saying the location of this adapter should basically be on the modem from which I retrieve this wifi signal?

Comment: My PC is connect to the network using cable, as is the TV, so can I do this without any wifi adapters, you mention

Comment: @JimLowe no, the WiDi capable adapter has to be on your PC. You will not be able to display a desktop over ethernet, as only WiDi exists for this

Comment: Can I buy both for TV and /pc ?

Comment: @JimLowe You can buy a WiDi adapter for PC, but you'll need a new TV if your current doesn't support it.